Matter.js applying an impulse similar to box2d / others
I am new to Matter.js,
I noticed there is no simple applyImpulse method similar to that in box2d where you can bass it X and Y coordinates and it will apply an impulse on the body from that direction. Is there an equivelant method or process that I am missing?
I did try adding a one-time force with the applyForce method but no luck as the shape in question went flying.

applyForce is it. Please share your non-working code as a [mcve] and maybe try using smaller force values.
